# How to add new column from array to Vaex dataframe after filtered?

Tags: python, vaex

I have data file 'for-filter.txt'

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
2,6,7,8
-1,2,3,4
4,5,5,5
-2,3,3,3
```

Vaex code that I am doing

```
import vaex as vx 
import numpy as np
df_vaex = vx.from_csv('for-filter.txt')
df_filter = df_vaex[df_vaex['a'] > 0]
df_filter.head()
df_filter['e'] = np.repeat("value", 3)
```

I want to add column "e" to `df_filter`, I got error

```
Array is of length 3, while the length of the DataFrame is 3 due to the filtering, the (unfiltered) length is 5.
```

I just care about dataframe with length 3 because I just discard useless row. But somehow Vaex want me to have length 5.

The similar code in pandas should run as expected

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_pd = pd.read_csv('for-filter.txt')
df_filter_pd = df_pd[df_pd['a'] > 0]
df_filter_pd.head()
df_filter_pd.loc[:, "e"] = np.repeat("value", 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved

```
import vaex as vx 
import numpy as np
df_vaex = vx.from_csv('for-filter.txt')
df_filter = df_vaex[df_vaex['a'] > 0]
df_filter.head()
df_filter = df_filter.extract()  # add this line to make real dataframe from lazy indexing
df_filter['e'] = np.repeat("value", 3)
```